# mysql utf8 encoding and unique keys

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, collation, unique-index

I am inporting data fom a user table (many users from many sites):
`myisam default collation latin1_swedish`....

Importing that data into a `innodb table utf8_general`

I have placed a unique key on the `username,site_id` combination but this is failing on 2 users of the same site:

```
user 1    dranfog,
user 2    drånfog
```

If I run:

```
SELECT IF('å' = 'a', 'yep', 'nope');
```

directly on the target db with utf8 encoding, I get `'yep'`.

Any tips on resolving this most welcome. I was of impression utf8 would treat these as different charcters but that seem to not be the case.

Comment: (nitpicking) but there is coalition :)

Comment: pleeze exsqueuez my dislecksia

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Collations that end with `_ci` are case (and accent) insensitive.

You could change the collation to '`utf8_binary'` to treat `dranfog` differently than `drånfog`.