# Mysql Unique index o = ö?

Tags: mysql, unique

I have a table with this columns:

id,actor

actor is a unique column (utf8_general_ci (I tried utf8_unicode_ci as well)

I have one entry:

1,Robert_Lohr

and I want to add

Robert_Löhr but MySql says that it's not possible because of a duplicate entry.

Any idea how to fix this? I have a lot of umlauts and characters like è or é and I want that it works with all of this. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql utf8 encoding and unique keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808874/mysql-utf8-encoding-and-unique-keys)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is MySQL treating é the same as e?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919902/why-is-mysql-treating-e-the-same-as-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the  `utf8_bin` collation would help, but in this case it will be case-sensitive...